# Call to undefined method App\User::admin() error in Session in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to put some sessions in my project and it's working fine when I'm logged out. But when I'm logged in as an Admin I'm getting the following error:

> Call to undefined method App\User::admin()

this is my routes

```
Route::resource('/create','PagesController@showCreate')->middleware(IsAdmin::class);
Route::get('/users','UserController@index')->middleware(IsAdmin::class);
Route::get('/verify','UserController@userVerify')->middleware(IsAdmin::class);
```

this is my User model

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *  protected $table = 'users';
    *public $primaryKey ='id';
     * @var array
     */
  
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','userType',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'admin' => 'boolean',
    ];

    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

    public function isAdmin()
    {
        return $this->admin;
    }
   
}
```

and this is my IsAdmin class

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class IsAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        {
            if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->admin() )
            {
                return $next($request);
            }
    
            return redirect('home');
        }
    }
}
```

And every time I try to redirect to other routes I get the same error except for the dashboard

Comment: Please share your, IsAdmin & User model class

Comment: there i shared it

Comment: what is `$this->admin;` inside model do you have `admin` column in `users` table?

Comment: Where is the method `admin()` coming from? I can see `isAdmin()` but not `admin()`.

Comment: i have admin in users table

Comment: if I remove admin() and replacecd it with IsAdmin i will be redirected to home

Comment: If my answer not works please share your user schema, or explain `$this->admin` in your user model, is it a boolean column on your users table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change if statement in your IsAdmin class:

```
if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin() )
```

Comment: Im being redirected to home